# How can I create a $1 14-day in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'd like to create a $1, 14-day trial for my monthly subscription, however Stripe currently only has the ability to create free trials.

Here's what I'm thinking, but I can't figure out how to implement it:

1. Create a product that costs $1.
2. Create a monthly subscription that has a 14-day free trial.
3. When someone purchases the $1 product, they are automatically signed up for the monthly subscription.

Has anyone else successfully accomplished this? Any ideas?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do this with Stripe's subscriptions and some custom development on your end. The idea is to use [Invoice Items](https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions#adding-invoice-items) to charge the $1 setup fee for the trial. Since invoice items get added to the upcoming invoice automatically, you would follow this flow:

- Create the customer via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer).
- Create the $1 Invoice Item via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem).
- Create the subscription to your monthly plan with a 14 days trial via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription).

The last step automatically creates the first $0 invoice for the trial and adds the invoice item which would charge the customer $1. After 14 days, if the subscription is not canceled the customer would start getting charged the plan price every month.

Answer (score -5):

Unable to create 1$ payment  in stripe. It shows wrong error message